# change table pagesize dynamic in java struts

Tags: java, jquery, struts

i use java struts framework. in list page, record is listed on table

```
<display:table class="table980" id="table1" name="sessionScope.ruhsatListe" 
     sort="list" pagesize="100" requestURI="/IletimAction.do?target=rListele"    
export="true">
<display:column class="tableItem" property="sicilNo" title="Sicil No" sortable="true" headerClass="tableColHeadingSort" />
```

i want to change pagesize attr. listing 10 record or 50 record or 100

i used jquery but not working and code is:

```
function(deger){
    location.reload();
$("#table1").removeAttr("pagesize");
$("#table1").attr('pagesize', deger);
 }
```

what can i change pagesize as dynamic? i use jquery

Answer (score 1):

When your jsp tag gets evaluated at the server, it gets converted to simple html tags and your attributes would probably disappear by the time it reaches the browser for rendering. So simply changing pageSize attribute at browser will not help.

What you need to do is a server hit, something like,

```
$.get('/IletimAction.do?target=rListeleTable', function (tableData) {
    // Replace your entire table content with tableData
})
```

Needless to say `/IletimAction.do?target=rListeleTable` (Note the difference in URL with yours) should return your updated `<display:table/>` jsp content.

This is only one way of doing this, there might be better ways, if you can check [Struts Ajax documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/ajax.html).

Comment: we use struts 1.0 framework and not support ajax. what suggestion else?

Comment: For Struts 1.0, I think the one I gave is the best.